# Prove that there is a unique positive real number m with two desired properties

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

This is an exercise from Velleman's "How To Prove It".

Prove that there is a unique positive real number $m$ that has the following two properties:

- For every positive real number $x$, $x/(x+1) <m$
- If y is any positive real number with the property that for every positive real number $x$, $x/(x+1)<y$, then $m≤y$

$∃!m∈R^+[∀x∈R^+(x/(x+1)<m)∧∀y∈R^+[(∀x∈R^+(x/(x+1)<y))→m≤y]]$

Proof:

Existence: Let $m=1∈R^+$
. Now let $x∈R^+$
be arbitrary. Suppose $x/(x+1)≥m$
. Then $x≥mx+m=x+1$
, and $0≥1$
, which is a contradiction. Thus, $x/(x+1)<m$
. Now let $y∈R+$
be arbitrary such that $∀x∈R+(x/(x+1)<y)$
. Suppose that$ m=1>y$
. Now consider $x=y/(1−y)∈R^+$
, which is defined since $y<1$
.$ x/(x+1)=y/(1−y)/(y/(1−y+1))==y≥y$
. Thus, we have found an $x∈R^+$
such that $x/(x+1)≥y$
, which is a contradiction. It follows that $m≤y$
.
This is from another post([Prove that there is a unique positive real number $m$ with two desired properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705635/prove-that-there-is-a-unique-positive-real-number-m-with-two-desired-propertie)).

I was wondering how the choice of x=y/(1-y) was produced. I can follow it once it's been chosen, but before looking at the solutions, I would have had no idea how to strategically find one.

Thanks

Comment: Which choice of $y$? I see no choice there.

Comment: $y$ is _arbitrary_, all we want is that $y<1$. Then you find $x$ by solving the equation $\frac{x}{x+1}=y$ in $x$.

Comment: I mean choice of x = y (1-y). I've made the correction in the post

Answer (score 2):

You can produce $x$ by working backwards. A possible thought process might look like this:

We want to find $x$ where $\frac{x}{x+1} \ge y$ to show a contradiction. Let's write an equation that satisfies the inequality, then we can simply solve the equation. $\frac{x}{x+1} = y$ seems like a good choice. Solving:
$$
x = yx+y\\
(1-y)x = y\\
x = \frac{y}{1-y}
$$
Note that to be more clear and concise, the author presents $x = \frac{y}{1-y}$ first, then arrive at the contradiction.

Comment: Where $y \ne 1$ is the condition.